# Как при выборе пользователя на доске Jira, показывался список задач в которых человек добавлен во вкладке люди к задаче

Tags: jira

Как в Jira сделать чтобы список пользователей добавленных к определенной задаче отображался на доске при выборе соответствующего пользователя

Comment: непонятно. На какой доске?

Comment: Доска kanban необходимо добавить вот это - 

Когда вы выбираете определенного пользователя во вкладке "Люди" на доске Jira, будут отображаться только задачи, в которых этот пользователь участвует. Это включает задачи, в которых он является назначенным исполнителем (assignee), участником (participant) или отвечает за выполнение задачи в качестве другой роли.

Comment: ну так в вопросе написано совсем другое...

Comment: чем описывать словами, лучше картинку показать, чего хочется